# Javascript separate string with enter

Tags: javascript, processmaker

I want to put html script inside of `<div id>`, but I can't separate the string with enter. So I put the code like this (example):

```
var html = "<table style='width:100%'><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Age</th></tr>";

$("#panelChatlog").html(this.html);
```

as you can see the string is html code, but I want to separate html code so it's more readable like this:

```
var html = "
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
              <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        ";

$("#panelChatlog").html(this.html);
```

But it is impossible in my javascript. I am using processmaker 3.x
Any advise?

Comment: Change `$("#panelChatlog").html(this.html);` to `$("#panelChatlog").html(html);`. That's a `var` not a class or constructor property. Those are actually totally different, as one or more spaces is interpreted by the Browser as a single white space. This might work for a table, but it won't render the same otherwise.

Comment: Also, you have to use different quotes within quotes, or escape your quotes, or use template literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the ` was character introduced for, so you don't need to manually write `\n` in your strings. Just replacing the quotes is sufficient (make sure to close out your `table` tag):

```js
var html = `
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
              <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
          </table>
        `;

alert(html);
```

Comment: Everyone has same answers, I can't choose more than 1 answers but thanks for all of you who answer me.

Answer (score 4):

used ` character as said @Christian and user trim function remove whitespace from HTML code.

```js
var html = `
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
              <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        `;

 $("#panelChatlog").html(html.trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panelChatlog">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which is introduced in ES6.

```
const htmlMarkup = `
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
</table>`
```